# Comparing lists and giving score

Tags: python

I have problems when I try to compare two different lists within a `for` loop. The reason why I want to do this is because one of the lists are supposed to act as the correct one and the other one is someone's answer to a few questions. Therefore I want the lists to be compared to see how many one right the person who answered got. When I am running the code down below it does not work the way I want to and I cannot find the right way to do it...

```
answers = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]
correct = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
score = 0

for x in answer:
    for y in correct:
        if x == y:
            score += 1
            answer.pop(x)
            correct.pop(y)
        else:
            answer.pop(x)
            correct.pop(y)

print(score)
```

Comment: `for x, y in zip(answer, correct)` and you don't do the popping, just filter them out

Comment: `score = sum(a == b for a, b in zip(answers, correct))`…

Comment: Awesome!!! That worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
answers = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]
correct = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
score = 0

for x,y in zip(answers, correct):
    score += (x==y)

print(score)
```